# Conditional Select Statement with if else

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to select data from a row and then using that value input another predefined data value into a variable. I've got this, not sure if it's the correct syntax for SQL though.

```
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @server VARCHAR(15)

DECLARE response_cursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT col1, col3, col4 FROM [dbo].[tbl] WHERE [status] <> 'Decommission'

IF col3 ='ABCD'
    THEN @server = 'Server1';
ELSIF col3 ='DEFS'
    THEN @server = 'Server2';
ELSIF col3 ='THSE'
    THEN @server = 'Server3';
...
ELSE col3 = NULL
    THEN @server = Null
END IF;
```

I get this when I try and run it:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'then'.

This is running on a MS SQL 2012 server

Here's the entire sql statement I'm working on; might help to better explain what I'm trying to do.

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_anotherprocedure]

as
begin


-- begin loop processing to get a response for each record in the validation     table

DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @server varchar(15)
DECLARE @port nvarchar(5)

declare response_cursor cursor
    for select ID, COL3, Assigned_Port  from [dbo].[tbl] where [Status] <>     'Decommission' -- we dont want to process decommissioned ports

    if COL3='123'
        begin @server = 'ABC'; end
    IF COL3='456'
        begin @server = 'DEF'; end
    IF COL3='789'
        begin @server = 'HIJ'; end
    ELSE COL3 = NULL
        begin @server = '' END


open response_cursor
fetch next from response_cursor  -- get the first record
INTO @ID, @SERVER, @PORT

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- make the  call
    DECLARE @RC int
    DECLARE @request nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @out nvarchar(max)

   --set @server = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'   --ip address of the server
   --set @port = '101010'               --port of the server
   set @request = '"some_parmamet'  

    EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[sp_stored] 
        @server
        ,@port
        ,@request
        ,@out output

    -- UPDATE THE RESPONSE FIELD FOR THE CURRENT RECORD WITH THE RESPONSE     FROM THE REQUEST
/*   UPDATE [dbo].[tbl]
        set response = @out
        where ID = @ID

    fetch next from response_cursor  -- get the next record and repeat  request
    into @ID, @SERVER, @PORT
*/
    Print @out
    END 

close response_cursor
deallocate response_cursor


end
```

Comment: Change THEN to SET for starters.

Comment: Don't you need to read the cursor?

Comment: @jarlh good point. I didnt even go their because the question was related to if/then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a few issues here:

```
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @server VARCHAR(15)

DECLARE response_cursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT col1, col3, col4 FROM [dbo].[tbl] WHERE [status] <> 'Decommission'
```

**For your first if**

```
IF col3 ='ABCD'
    BEGIN SET @server = 'Server1'; END
```

**There is no ELSE/IF IN SQL that I am aware of.**

```
IF col3 ='DEFS'
    BEGIN SET @server = 'Server2'; END

IF col3 ='THSE'
    BEGIN SET @server = 'Server3'; END
```

Yuu dont need an END IF. You do a BEGIN/END for each IF. Also if you need to do you can use ELSE

the structure is

```
IF something BEGIN dosomething END
ELSE
BEGIN doSomethingElse END
```

If you really need to use the IF/THEN/ELSE model, you can always do it using CASE

That structure is

```
SELECT CASE WHEN someCritera then dosomething
WHEN someCriteria then doSomething
...
--after your final when/then end with an END
```

[For reference purposes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587.aspx)

Comment: Tried using the if/begin syntax however every line was an error. In effect what I need to do is take data from the table and compare it to an array I'm building so I can loop through and then output the results to another table.

The error was an incorrect syntax near '@server'

Comment: ohhhh use SET @server = 'XXX'

Comment: Looks closer to correct, I have 8 total IF statements and then the ELSE statement. The first 2 IF statements pass the error check in SQL however the following 6 statements plus the ELSE statement are saying "Incorrect Syntax near IF expected CONVERSATION" --NEVER MIND, I needed to drop the END from the SET statement

Comment: Now to figure out why "COL3" is being shown as an invalid column name. I think its a syntax thing, it'll have to wait until Monday.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` statement for a cleaner code.

```
SELECT @server = (
  CASE col3
    WHEN '123' THEN 'ABC'
    WHEN '456' THEN 'DEF'
    WHEN '789' THEN 'GHI'
    ELSE ''
  END)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE
    WHEN col3 = 'ABCD' THEN 'Server1'
    WHEN col3 = 'DEFS' THEN 'Server2'
    WHEN col3 = 'THSE' THEN 'Server3'
ELSE NULL END as @server
```